# consulta para obtener dias en la misma fila

Tags: sql, subconsultas

hola buenos días  tengo una tabla detalle horario que tiene como atributo días y tienen (Lunes , Martes,etc) lo que me causa complicaciones es que esos días los quiero en una misma fila y que se muestren todos los días pero no se como implementar quise hacer con subconsultas pero nada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que motor de base de datos?

Comment: Especifica en las etiquetas qué base de datos estás utilizando, y muestra tu consulta y la salida _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más sencillo es hacerlo mediante un agregado condicional que te permite convertir filas en columnas. Este código, además, está dentro del estándar y funciona con cualquier motor de base de datos con mínimos cambios (solo para delimitar las cadenas).

```
SELECT id_h_laboral,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Lunes"     THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Lunes,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Martes"    THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Martes,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Miercoles" THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Miercoles,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Jueves"    THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Jueves,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Viernes"   THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Viernes,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Sabado"    THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Sabado,
    MAX( CASE WHEN dia = "Domingo"   THEN dia ELSE NULL END) AS Domingo
FROM detalle_horario
WHERE id_h_laboral = 1
GROUP BY id_h_laboral;
```

Comment: pero sien dado caso quisiera que me mostrara todos los registros de esa forma sin el where funcionaria ?

Comment: muchas gracias si me funciono enserio gracias

Comment: Si esta respuesta te ayudo no olvides marcarla.

Comment: Sin el `WHERE` te mostrará una fila por cada valor único de `id_h_laboral`.